# Peculiar volley error with OptionMenu android

Tags: android, android-volley, android-optionsmenu

I am making a simple app for an academic management system for a university.
Initially, I had a MainActivity with an options menu loaded from an xml file, and a request being called to an API, both of which were successful.
Then, I added an onCreateOptionsMenu() method to the MainActivity. This led to the crash of the app, and the debug messages suggested that the request to the same API was giving an error.

My code for the onCreateOptionsMenu() is

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Entered onCreateOptionsMenu");

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.drawermenu, menu);
        //super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        MenuItem courseitem = menu.findItem(R.id.courses);
        SubMenu coursemenu = courseitem.getSubMenu();

        //The CourseObject contained Json of user and courses..So courses now has only course specific json..
        JSONArray courses = null;
        if( SessionManager.getCourseData()==null){
            Log.d(TAG,"coursedata is empty");
            callCourse();
        }

        try {
            courses = (JSONArray)SessionManager.getCourseData().get("courses");
        } 
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String coursecode = "";
        int courseId = 0;
        //For Loop for adding courses to submenu
        for (int i = 0; i < courses.length(); i++){
            JSONObject course = null;
            try
            {
                course = courses.getJSONObject(i);
                //Log.d(TAG, course.toString());
                coursecode = (String) course.get("code");
                courseId = (int) course.get("id");
            } 
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            coursemenu.add(Menu.NONE,courseId,Menu.NONE,coursecode);
        }


        return true;
    }
```

The code for my volley request is

```
//this is entered when the user has just logged in...
Log.d(TAG, "calling course api");
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this,       SessionManager.httpStack);
//requestqueue is made using http-stack as we need to check the sessions of the logged in user
JsonObjectRequest courseRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
    (Request.Method.GET, course_url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject> () {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            //pDialog.setMessage("Response: "+ response.toString());
            //0th element of the course object now has the response
            courseobject[0] = response;
            Log.d(TAG,"success");
            //So the dialog box is hid now...
            //pDialog.hide();
            if (courseobject[0] != null)
            {
                //Also the Course data is put in a hash map of the Session Manager Preferences so that we dont need to call this API again...
                SessionManager.setCourseData(courseobject[0]);
                Log.d(TAG, "setting course data in cookie");

                // Setup UI elements
                setup();

                // Call home fragment - course buttons created there
                FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new FragmentHome()).commit();

                callGrades();
            }
            else
            {
                //The Response is null and the user is not registered in any course till now...
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not registered for any course", LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
        {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            //pDialog.setMessage(error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to fetch course data", LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //pDialog.setMessage(error.getCause().toString());
            //pDialog.hide();
        }
    });
```

//Course Request is now added to the Request Queue...
requestQueue.add(courseRequest);

The error messages in the log are (after formatting)

```
Entered onCreateOptionsMenu
coursedata is empty
http://10.192.44.89:8000/courses/list.json
calling course api
AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
I/System.out: Thread-31118(ApacheHTTPLog):isSBSettingEnabled false
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.quantumcoder.moodleplus, PID: 30013
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method java.lang.Object org.json.JSONObject.get(java.lang.String) on a null object reference
at com.example.quantumcoder.moodleplus.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:290)
at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2959)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:298)
at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:85)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:243)
at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:85)
at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:448)
at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:65)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6145)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

The code for drawermenu.xml where I am dynamically creating items is

```
    <item
        android:title="courses"
        android:id="@+id/courses">
        <menu >                              <!-- add courses here -->
            <item
                android:title="course1"
                android:icon="@drawable/courses"
                android:id="@+id/nav_item_courses"/>
            <item
                android:title="course2"
                android:icon="@drawable/bin"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think the problem is here - course = courses.getJSONObject(i); because your response JsonObject is returning null.

Comment: But the callCourse() method, which is called before that, is supposed to fetch the object (obtained as a response from a volley request). Hence, the problem is with volley. The debug  log suggests that the volley request returns an error response, while the same request returns a successful response without the onCreateOptionsView() method.